# How to move the yaxis label to the right side of the primefaces chart

Tags: primefaces, pchart

Move the y-axis label to the right side of the prime-faces chart.

Comment: What have you tried after searching on google ? Plz post the relevant code you have tried on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question.
Set the yaxis values as y2axis in seriesDefaults object.

i.e, this.cfg.seriesDefaults.yaxis='y2axis';

i will move the yaxis label to the right side of the primefaces chart